# Resizing a JQuery Draggable element's containment parent while dragging

Tags: jquery, triggers, draggable

I have a div 'slide' element within another div 'box' parent container and have applied JQuery Draggable to the child.  While the item is being dragged, I'm resizing the parent container, sometimes shrinking, sometimes enlarging it.

The problem is that JQuery doesn't respond to this resizing and still contains the dragged element within the original dimensions of the parent, rather than within its current size, until mouseup - the next drag session will use the new dimensions (until it changes again).

To try and solve this, I was hoping to trigger the mouseup event followed by the mousedown event, so that JQuery will use the new container size:

```
$('.slide').draggable({ axis: "x", containment: 'parent',
                    drag: function (e, ui) {
                        resizeContainer();

                        if (outsideContainer()){

                        // Try to stop and restart dragging
                            $(this).trigger('mouseup');
                            $(this).trigger('mousedown');
                        }
                    }
```

However, this throws an exception...

```
Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined
```

...on this line of JQuery code:

```
this.helper[0].style.left=this.position.left+"px";
```

Anyone know how I can either a) get Draggable to respond real-time to the change in parent dimensions or b) trigger a dragstop and then dragend seamlessly?

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I know that I can use return false to end the dragging, but I need this to be invisible to the user, so they can continue moving their mouse to drag the element, without having to mouseup and back down again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Fijjit, if I understand correctly, what you want is a custom "containment" function, which implements your `resizeContainer` algorithm before applying bounds to the dragged element.

In the code below,

- the standard `draggable containment` option is omitted
- `resizeContainer` is attached as the `draggable drag` event handler
- `resizeContainer` is dual purpose; (a) it performs your resize algorithm and (b) applies the custom containment algorithm

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    var $container = $("#myContainer");

    function resizeContainer(e, ui) {
        //implement container resize algorithm here
        var w1 = ui.helper.outerWidth(),
            w2 = $container.width();
        ui.position.left = Math.max(Math.min(ui.position.left, w2 - w1), 0);
    }

    $("#draggable").draggable({
        axis: "x",
        drag: resizeContainer
    });
});
```

See [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XLrNF/)

Comment: Fantastic - thanks a lot.  I was aware of the ui value passed in, but hadn't figured the .position.left value would actually affect the position (I assumed it was read only).  What I was doing was trying to set the css (style.left) of the object, but I guess JQuery was overriding that in the end.

Comment: No worries. The hard bit was knowing to use `.outerWidth()` for the helper and `.width()` for the container. This matters when the elements have padding and/or borders otherwise calculated containment boundary gave a nasty visual overlap error at the rightmost limit of travel.