# jquery draggable - resize selector while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, resize, draggable

I have a problem with Jquery draggable, I want to drag a DIV and while dragged I will resize the DIV. Seems like Jquery calculate the height/width of the Selector just at initiation, after resize it will calculate the height/width from the begining not the actual/live and if I use a container it will not work properly.

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/zwQ2S/

```
$("#selector").draggable({ containment: "#container", scroll: false});
$("#selector").draggable( "option", "axis", "y");
$("#container").mousemove(function() {
var margin =parseInt($("#selector").css("top"));
    if (margin > 10){
   $("#selector").css("height", "100px");
    }
});
```

PS: I want to use draggable for a scrollbar with dynamic content/loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456234/resizing-a-jquery-draggable-elements-containment-parent-while-dragging), the final fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XLrNF/178/

```
     var $container = $("#demo");
function resizeContainer(e, ui) {
    //resize container here
    var w1 = ui.helper.outerHeight(),
        w2 = $container.height();
    //console.log([ui.position.left, w1, w2].join(' : '));
    ui.position.top = Math.max(Math.min(ui.position.top, w2 - w1), 0);
}
$("#draggable").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    drag: resizeContainer
});
```