# css scaled (-webkit-transform) div and it's child with jquery ui draggable moves not same as cursor during dragging

Tags: jquery, css, draggable, scale, css-transforms

I have a window with a child inside. Child should be moving inside window.
Window is scaled using css transform (-webkit-transform).
I tried something like this:

```
html
<div class="window">
    <div class="rect"></div>
</div>​

css
.window
{
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-25%, -25%) scale(0.5);
}

.rect
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
}

js
$(function() {
    $('.rect').draggable({
        containment: 'parent'
    });
});​
```

​
I've posted it here - http://jsfiddle.net/bLKQj/12/
The child moves slowly than cursor. If scaling will be >1 it will be moves faster. Howto fix it?

PS: In transform `translate(-25%, -25%)` is for make scaling with fixed top-left corner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Drag/Resize with CSS Transform Scale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212683/jquery-drag-resize-with-css-transform-scale)

Comment: To modify the center of your transformation, preferably use the transform origin and not translate: `-webkit-transform-origin: 0; /* will transform from the top left corner */`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say why do you need to use a CSS transform? You should really avoid them whenever possible, because they're not well supported and they have unintended consequences like this. Can you just specify different height and width?