# jQuery Drag with CSS Transform with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to scale an element and drag this element to do a WorkSpace that can work in all screen resolutions.

The problem I have it that I can't do it works fine. If you try the Fiddle Code you can see that the elements that is being resized doesn't going to the final corner. I have read a lot of post like this ([jQuery Drag/Resize with CSS Transform Scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212683/jquery-drag-resize-with-css-transform-scale)) but the problem is when you reference a containment.

The fiddle code with the error example:

http://jsfiddle.net/yeD4b/4/

Updated: added text too

**HTML**

```
<div id="containerDragable">
<img id="img_messi" style="display: inline; position: absolute; z-index: 101; " src="http://www.elconfidencial.com/fotos/noticias_2011/2012090245messi_dentro.jpg" />

<div id="text_example">hi!</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  #containerDragable {
    width: 80vw; 
    height: 45vw;
    background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position:absolute;
}

#img_messi
{
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;   
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    position:absolute;
}
#text_example
{
    font: normal 36px arial,sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;   
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
        $('#img_messi').draggable({
            containment: "#containerDragable", cursor: "move", scroll: false

        });
    });

$(function () {
        $('#text_example').draggable({
            containment: "#containerDragable", cursor: "move", scroll: false

        });
    });
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `CSS` to scale your image. Use `jQuery` instead :

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeD4b/1/)

```
$('#img_messi').width($('#img_messi').width()/2);
```

**Edit :**

To fit better to your needs, if you **have** to use the `scale` css property, you should use this simple workaround with negatives margins :

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeD4b/5/)

```
$(this).css('margin', '0 -'+($(this).width()/2)+'px -'+($(this).height()/2)+'px 0');
```

That's quite ugly yet it works...

**Edit : with dynamic ratio**

Ok this is a tough one... The main trick here is to set the margin to top, right, bottom and left.

[The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yeD4b/6/)

See this :

```
var verticalOffset = ($(this).height() - $(this).height()*ratio)*0.5;
var horizontalOffset = ($(this).width() - $(this).width()*ratio)*0.5;
```

Here `$(this).height()` is the original height of the DOM (same for width). You substract to this itself times the ratio, and then divide the whole by 2 (`*0.5`) because the margins are on top **and** bottom (same for left and right).

Comment: The problem is that it could be text too, I'm going to update the post. Thanks.

Comment: As long as your text box is not inline, this should not be a problem

Comment: My text I updated the code, please check! ;) Thanks in advance! Regards!

Comment: You mean, you want the text to size down, not just the dimensions of his box ?

Comment: I want to size down all the elements inside the "draggable workspace", like works Desktop Apps

Comment: I think that the problem is in the width and the height of the element draggable, the jQuery UI thinks that it has not change... (if you see the inspecto, the size is 200x200).

Comment: Ok, I understood your solution because in this moment, I'm scaling 0.5 and your code update to two (double)... if the scaling is dinamyc, could your code works? Thank you so much...

Comment: Yes, when resizing the object, you simply call this line changing the `$(this).width()/2` by `$(this).width()*ratio` and then change the css using jQuery.

Comment: Well, there is a small mistake in my code. I will edit this soon using dynamic ratio

Comment: Wow that was quite tricky ! You will have some issues with handle but I'll let you find out how to correct this

Comment: If you help me to solve the problem with the cursor, you will be my hero :)

Comment: And another problem... if you change the screen size, the image is out... why?

Comment: Well, it is quite hard to achieve all this... I would recommand you to use [jQuery.resizable()](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#constrain-area) from `jQuery UI` and see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10212683/jquery-drag-resize-with-css-transform-scale).