# Sortable with individually CSS3 scaled connected containers not working properly for moving to following containers

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I recently started a bounty for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24970789) in hopes of resolving similar issues I had with jQuery UI sortables and CSS3 scaled containers. However, my case is more complex.

Furthermore, only later on did I realize I needed to disallow overflowing of the containers' contents. Therefor I had to set `overflow: hidden` on them and have the `ui.helper` be cloned and appended to `document.body`. Luckily, that actually seemed to simplify adjusting the `ui.helper`, in that I only needed to copy `transform` and `transform-origin` to play nice with its positioning.

However, after fiddling around with the other suggested idea, [given in the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36684822), about adjusting the `item` dimensions, I still can't seem to make my case work.

Please [see my case in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yp0rj584/). For a better experience of the problem I would suggest to [view the result pane individually](https://jsfiddle.net/yp0rj584/embedded/result/).

The problem is that when I try to move an item to a container *following* its current container, jQuery UI has problems detecting the intersection. This appears to have something to do with the perceived width of either the item itself *or* the `ui.helper`, since moving to preceding containers seem to work fine. However, I'm just not sure where to look.

And even though I suspect [`refreshPositions()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/sortable.js#L817) is relevant to my problem — which is basically what I'm trying to accomplish in `fixStart()`, but for *all* containers — it doesn't appear to do a whole lot.

My question, therefor, is: what is it that actually needs to be adjusted for jQuery UI to properly detect intersections, in this case?

---

Edit: [I've managed to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821684), but I'd still love to see a "cleaner" solution, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to figure out how to get it to work, myself.

The problem actually has to do with the calculated container widths. These are cached inside `refreshPositions()`, but since *those* are the ones that actually have the CSS3 `transform` applied to them, the cached values are not calculated (to scale) properly.

Luckily, I came across an undocumented option: [`custom.refreshContainers`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/sortable.js#L855), which is a callback that, when defined, will be called from within `refreshPositions()`, allowing you to substitute the `containerCache` calculations.

So, I amended my code with the following:

```js
function fixRefreshContainers() {
  this.containers.forEach( function( container ) {
    var scale = getScale( container.element );
    var offset = container.element.offset();
    container.containerCache.left   = offset.left;
    container.containerCache.top    = offset.top;
    container.containerCache.width  = container.element.width()  * scale.x;
    container.containerCache.height = container.element.height() * scale.y;
  } );
}

$( 'div.chapter' ).sortable( {
  /* omitted earlier options, for brevity */
  custom: {
    refreshContainers: fixRefreshContainers
  }
} );
```

You can [see it in action in the adjusted fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yp0rj584/2/).

So far, this seems to works beautifully, but I'd still like to know if there's a solution possible that doesn't utilize the undocumented `custom.refreshContainers` callback.