# jQuery UI Sortable item jump on start

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Hy guys, I have a weird issue witj jQuery sortable that I don't know how to solve.

I have created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/44LgX/

My js code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

$( '.v-content-container' ).sortable({
    placeholder : 'v-column-placeholder',
    start       : function( e, ui ){
        ui.placeholder.width( ui.item.width() );
        ui.placeholder.height( ui.item.height() );
    }
});

});
```

Basically, each row consists of two columns which are sortable within that single row. Why 3 rows? Just for demo purposes, count does not matter.

Now, you can demo the issue by trying to drag the second column to first position. You will notice that immediately after you start dragging, the element will jump off the pointer to the bottom left part of the screen.

Now, I did some digging, and it seems I am not the only one with this issue. Proposed solution was to use helper: clone as a sortable parameter, but that does not fit my needs and I also want to solve my original issue, rather than going around it.

Any help or insight is wellcome, thanks!

Comment: Seems to work fine under chrome

Comment: Hmm weird, I tested on both FF and Chrome (latest versions on Windows) and it happens on both.

Answer (score 1):

this is more a place to get started, as I have to head out to a meeting.

when i get rid of all your css, there is no problem.  [fiddle with bare bones css](http://jsfiddle.net/dfygrvty/44LgX/2/)

however, it looks like crap.  how to find the offending css?  i go binary search.  get rid of half the css, still have a problem --> no, add in 1/2 of the remaining missing css --> yes, remove 1/2 the loaded css.  repeat until you get close to the offending lines.

I'm looking for the offending css atm, but if you beat me to it feel free to post your own answer.  so far the 'clicking moves the item' issue appears because of these lines.  :

```
.v-row-fluid .v-span12 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 99.94680851063829%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span11 {
    width: 91.48936170212765%;
    *width: 91.43617021276594%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span10 {
    width: 82.97872340425532%;
    *width: 82.92553191489361%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span9 {
    width: 74.46808510638297%;
    *width: 74.41489361702126%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span8 {
    width: 65.95744680851064%;
    *width: 65.90425531914893%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span7 {
    width: 57.44680851063829%;
    *width: 57.39361702127659%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span6 {
    width: 48.93617021276595%;
    *width: 48.88297872340425%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span5 {
    width: 40.42553191489362%;
    *width: 40.37234042553192%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span4 {
    width: 31.914893617021278%;
    *width: 31.861702127659576%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span3 {
    width: 23.404255319148934%;
    *width: 23.351063829787233%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span2 {
    width: 14.893617021276595%;
    *width: 14.840425531914894%;
}

.v-row-fluid .v-span1 {
    width: 6.382978723404255%;
    *width: 6.329787234042553%;
}
```

Comment: I'll be back after the meeting, but play with width specifications?

Comment: It seems to me as if the float:left is the culprit. If I instead use technique with display: inline-block, there is no issue, really weird.

Comment: good point, i didn't want to change your css, just find the parts that aren't mixing well with the post .sortable().  you of course know what you need to keep and what can be erased ;)  feel free to answer your own question, as I won't be back for an hour

Answer (score 1):

`zoom` and `scale`/`scale3d` cause this. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882213/how-to-combine-jquery-ui-draggable-sortable-stuff-with-custom-scale-code).

The reason ? jQuery-ui doesn't factor scale values into its drag offsets.