# Angular + ui-sortable lists: CTRL-mousewheel zoom vs normal mousewheel zoom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, jquery-ui-sortable

My understanding is that CTRL-mousewheel zooms are an accessibility feature, built into the browser in question (I am currently testing in Chrome and Opera, both if which use the CTRL- zoom).

This won't ever really be needed for accessibility, however, as the app will not be for the general public. And CTRL-wheel zoom has a nice benefit out-of-box as compared with standard mousewheel zoom over elements: It seems that Angular `ui-sortable`s work perfectly at any zoom/scale.

Unfortunately, from other answers I've found on SO, there is no way, when using CTRL-wheel, to zoom *selectively* : the browser can only zoom *everything*. For me, this includes `position:fixed` overlays scaling at the same time as the main viewport, which is no good.

So I set up some code for scrolling as per whichever element the mouse cursor is over, eg. scale the main viewport using the mousewheel, only if the mouse if over that viewport element.

The problem is that `ui-sortable` does *not* behave correctly, when using it for only a single element. I've used `scale` with `transform-origin` set at `50% 50%` but still, when I drag the `ui-sortable`s at any scale other than 1:1, they appear way off to the left. Any ideas on how to begin to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem in [Angular's sortable adaptation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable), rather it's an issue in the underlying jQuery-ui 1.9.2 positioning functions around line 4000 (`_generatePosition` or maybe one of the others). I believe that as the browser does not modify the actual dimension values during `scale` or `zoom`, and the formulae provided in that library do not account for scaling (that I can see), there is no easy fix, since jQuery `ui.sortable` needs scale-accurate values to calculate correct displacements. (I tried modifying the formula to account for this, but without success.)

The simplest workaround for the present is to manually change the `width()` / `height()` of your individual list elements, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882213/how-to-combine-jquery-ui-draggable-sortable-stuff-with-custom-scale-code). This may require being selective about just *what* you scale using `width()` / `height()`, and what you change using `scale` (which is generally easier).